# Title on horizontal navigation bar with dots in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

I am designing website using fullpage.js. I want to give title to each dot in horizontal navigation bar.

```
function addSlidesNavigation(section, numSlides){
        section.append('<div class="fp-slidesNav"><ul></ul></div>');
        var nav = section.find('.fp-slidesNav');

        //top or bottom
        nav.addClass(options.slidesNavPosition);

        for(var i=0; i< numSlides; i++){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>');
        }

        //centering it
        nav.css('margin-left', '-' + (nav.width()/2) + 'px');

        nav.find('li').first().find('a').addClass('active');
}
```

function call from :

```
if(options.slidesNavigation){
    addSlidesNavigation($(this), numSlides);
}
```

This function generates horizontal navigation bar. I want to add title for each. I am not getting how do I do it. Please help.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by following way.

In index page:     `horizontalNavigationToolTip = ['tooltip1','tooltip2'],`

in jquery.fullpage.js:

```
function addSlidesNavigation(section, numSlides){
        section.append('<div class="fp-slidesNav"><ul></ul></div>');
        var nav = section.find('.fp-slidesNav');

        //top or bottom
        nav.addClass(options.slidesNavPosition);

        for(var i=0; i< numSlides; i++){
            //nav.find('ul').append('<li><a href="#" title="'+ tooltip[i] +'"><span></span></a></li>');

            // Only add tooltip if needed (defined by user)
            var tooltip = options.horizontalNavigationToolTip[i];

            var li = '<li><a class="tooltips" href="#"><span></span><div><img src="images/tooltip/'+ tooltip +'.png" /></span></div></a>';
            li += '</li>';

            nav.find('ul').append(li);
        }

        //centering it
        nav.css('margin-left', '-' + (nav.width()/2) + 'px');

        nav.find('li').first().find('a').addClass('active');
    }
```

hope this is helpful to others.