# fullPage.js SLIDE tooltips

Tags: tooltip, slide, fullpage.js

I posted another question earlier today about the fantastic [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) plugin, but seeing as how I have multiple questions about it, I figure I'll ask them separately.

I'm creating a page that combines horizontal and vertical navigation, where I'm using horizontal for section navigation and vertical for slide navigation. Is there any way to make and insert tooltips for slides, similar to how there are tooltips for sections?

In my research I've found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318492/title-on-horizontal-navigation-bar-with-dots-in-fullpage-js) that indeed seems like it might hold the solution, but due to my unfortunately poor understanding of js I am unable to translate the solution provided there to slides within a section.

I greatly appreciate any assistance that can be offered. Thank you. Best, Nick

Comment: If you really need it and don't know enough jQuery you'd better ask for a customization of the plugin.